# iOS - Multiple Notification Extension Service?

Tags: ios, swift, service, notifications, extension-methods

Is it possible to have **Multiple Notification Service Extension** in one app? If Yes, then how to recognize which one will be used and how?

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't the use of **Notification Service Extension** is generic , so you can think of it to handle any mutable notification with

> "mutable-content":1